# Does fingerprint template "SAGEM_PKMAT" receive byte array? or some conversion required?

Tags: android, arrays, xml, bluetooth, datatemplate

XML CODE

```
<FINGER_TEMPLATE>

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

</FINGER_TEMPLATE>

<TEMPLATE_TYPE>
SAGEM_PKMAT
</TEMPLATE_TYPE>
```

Android: 
I have a byte-array containing fingerprint image data received from Bluetooth

```
byte[] bmpdata = getFingerprintImage(mUpImage,152,200);  //byte[] com.fgtit.reader.BluetoothReader.mUpImage
Bitmap image   = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bmpdata, 0,bmpdata.length);
fingerprintImage.setImageBitmap(image);
```

This finger-print image/Bytes will be sent to web-services. Does XML code receive byte array? Is there anything required to convert/send this byte array?

hihi "So Detailed Question" !

My answer is more or less here but not in JAVA/Android
Here's [a link] (ftp://38.227.249.11/TruTime/Outgoing/UNAM/Morpho%20Integrator%20Mkit%204.0x.pdf)

Comment: please make your question more readable!

Comment: It is readable now @milad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

encode your byte array in Base64 like this

```
byte[] bmpdata = getFingerprintImage(mUpImage,152,200);

String data = Base64.encodeToString(bmpdata , Base64.DEFAULT)
```

Upload string data on server and decode it again when fetch this string on android app.